# (django) Showing posts according to interests of users

Tags: python, django, listview, blogs

I am pretty new to Django and still learning it, but I have to create something like medium.com. I want to show posts to users according to their interests. I added an interests field with a checkbox in a sign-up form. And of course, I added a category to the Post model. So, how can I show (to logged-in users only) publications that they interested in?
Here is my models.py file in posts app

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('sport', 'Sport'),
        ('science', 'Science'),
        ('it', 'IT'),
        ('art', "Art"),
    )

    
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title for publication", max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(verbose_name="Category", choices=CATEGORY, max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey("accounts.User", verbose_name="Author:", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name="Body for publication")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date:", auto_now_add=True)
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And here is my vies.py file in posts app

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "index.html"    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "./posts/post_detail.html"

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "./posts/new_post.html"
    fields = '__all__'

class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "./posts/update_post.html"
    fields = ['body', 'title', 'category']

class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "./posts/delete_post.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')


class SportPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "./posts/sports.html"

class ITPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "./posts/it.html"

class SciencePostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "./posts/ilm-fan.html"

class ArtPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "./posts/sanat.html"
```

Here is my index.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% if object_list %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.pub_date }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.author }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.category }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No posts are available.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

This is my forms.py file in accounts app

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django import forms
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    INTERESTS = (
        ('sport', 'Sport'),
        ('science', 'Science'),
        ('it', 'IT'),
        ('art', "Art"),
        )
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='emailingiz', unique=True, default='')
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    interests = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=INTERESTS)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'interests', 'password1', 'password2')
```

And lastly this views.py file in accounts app

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import SignUpForm

class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

I have no idea how to do this, but I know that I have to do something in the views.py file in the posts app, however, I do not know what to do.
Will be really grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make another model `Category`. Since it will be its own model, you will be able to add future categories on the fly if needed, rather than having those hardcoded `choices`.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then your `User` and `Post` model will each have a `ManytoMany` field related to category. Posts can be tagged as certain categories when they are created, and Users will be able to select a number of categories that they are interested in and have them stored in this field:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
     interests = models.ManytoManyField(Category, default=None, blank=True)
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
     categories = models.ManytoManyField(Category, default=None, blank=True)
```

You can make use of a `forms.modelChoiceField` which will enable your user to select a category.

In your PostListView, all you need to do is change the `get_queryset` method to filter for posts that the user likes.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "index.html" 
   
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_interests = self.request.user.interests
        return Post.objects.filter(
        categories__in=user_interests).order_by('pub_date')
```

Then, you should get the posts that share categories with the user's interests.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but when I type ``` self.request.user.interest ``` it gives an AttributeErrror: saying that user object has no attribute named interests, how can I add this interests to list of attributes of User

Comment: @Nodirbek you will need to customize your user model (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). then you can add a field ```interests``` to the user model, as I showed in the answer. Then, you will be able to add interests to the user model in your ```SignUpView``` or otherwise with ```user.interests.add(category)``` where ```category``` is an instance of your ```category``` model.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I updated the forms.py, chage admin.py file did all things you said, but i got an eror when i try to to /signup page.

Comment: @Nodirbek you don't need to do anything to admin.py. You need to start by making sure your User model has M2M ```interests``` field related to ```category``` model. Then you can address the issues in your form and view which will allow you to add ```category``` model instances to this M2M relationship when the user signs up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error

```
Error during template rendering
In template /home/xesos/projects/mw/mw/templates/base.html, error at line 0

too many values to unpack (expected 2)
1   <!DOCTYPE html>
2   <html lang="en">
3   <head>
4       <meta charset="UTF-8">
5       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
6       <style>
7           
8       </style>
9       <title>
10          {% block title %}
```

To avoid this error I did some changes in forms.py, here is it

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from posts.models import Category

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    categories = Category.objects.values_list('name')
    listOfCategory = []
    listOfCategory += categories


    username = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    
    for i in range(0, len(listOfCategory)):
        listOfCategory.append(listOfCategory[i])
    interests = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in listOfCategory])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'interests', 'password1', 'password2')
```